# Difference between setattribute and addContent in jdom? I dont understand what is the difference

Tags: java, xml, jdom

Could someone explain what is the difference between setattribute and addContent in Jdom, when I use this for an element, could someone explain the difference?

I have read the API but I was unable to understand that

Comment: Attributes are the things inside the element open tag `<elem attr="value">`. Content is anything inside the actual element. `<elem>Some content</elem>`. Read the [javadoc](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/index.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you but when i make  for example elem.setAttribute(attr,value) woulld that be automatically <elm attr="value">?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setAttribute` sets an attribute for the given element.

[image]

[Attribute](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Attribute.html) is an XML attribute, so, if you have

```
<elem></elem>
```

and you call `setAttribute`, specifying that `attr` should have the value of `val`, then it will convert the above to

```
<elem attr="val"></elem>
```

`addContent` appends all children in the given collection to the end of the content list.

[image]

So, if you specify your children, then they will be added between the `>` and the `<` sign of the element, like

```
<elem>...</elem>
```

where ... represents whatever content you have defined.